# SparkContext parallelize invocation example in java

Tags: java, apache-spark

Am getting started with Spark, and ran into issue trying to implement the simple example for map function. The issue is with the definition of 'parallelize' in the new version of Spark. Can someone share example of how to use it, since the following way is giving error for insufficient arguments.

Spark Version : 2.3.2
Java : 1.8

```
SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("Compute Square of Numbers").config("spark.master","local").getOrCreate();
SparkContext context = session.sparkContext();
List<Integer> seqNumList = IntStream.rangeClosed(10, 20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
JavaRDD<Integer> numRDD = context.parallelize(seqNumList, 2);
```

Compiletime Error Message : The method expects 3 arguments

I do not get what the 3rd argument should be like? As per the documentation, it's supposed to be

```
scala.reflect.ClassTag<T>
```

But how to even define or use it?

Please do not suggest using JavaSparkContext, as i wanted to know how to get this approach to work with using generic SparkContext.

Ref : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#parallelize-scala.collection.Seq-int-scala.reflect.ClassTag-

Comment: **what** is the issue? Or shall we guess?

Comment: did you read the JavaDoc?? the method takes 3 arguments: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#parallelize-scala.collection.Seq-int-scala.reflect.ClassTag-

Comment: `scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Integer.class);`

Comment: and it also needs a Scala sequence: `JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(seqNumList)` - honestly, I don't know hwy you want to call this method in Java ... that's weird

Comment: @AKSW thanks for the ClassTag comment. That is what was looking for. I understand that this is not the optimal way, but wanted to understand how to use parallelize with SparkContext, since that is the new uniform way of accessing Spark processing. Or you suggest to fall back to JavaSparkContext for these tasks still?

Comment: @AKSW also update the question with more details. I am adding the final working code details. Please go ahead and suggest if there is better way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code which worked for me finally. Not the best way to achieve the result, but was a way to explore the API for me

SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("Compute Square of Numbers")
            .config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate();

```
SparkContext context = session.sparkContext();

List<Integer> seqNumList = IntStream.rangeClosed(10, 20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());


RDD<Integer> numRDD = context
        .parallelize(JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(seqNumList.iterator()).asScala()
                .toSeq(), 2, scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Integer.class));


numRDD.toJavaRDD().foreach(x -> System.out.println(x));
session.stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with providing the extra two parameters using `sparkConext`, you can also use `JavaSparkContext.parallelize()`, which only needs an input list:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD;

JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
final RDD<Integer> rdd = jsc.parallelize(seqNumList).map(num -> {
    // your implementation
}).rdd();
```